# How to determine the result of a code without running it

Tags: matlab

If I am given the code below, how can I tell what the resulting y-value would be. I apologize if this is a simple question but I find these types of questions very difficult.

For foo(-1,10)

```
function y = foo(x, a)
for k=-1:0
b=x-k;
while (x > -2) && (x < 2)
x=x+a+1;
end
end
y = b + x;
end
```

When running the programme I can see that b=10 but I don't understand how you get that. I would appreciate if someone could make this clearer for me.

Thank you!

Comment: Next time you could also consider using the [debug mode](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) of Matlab. That allows you to put stops anywhere in your program allowing you to see what the value of all variables at that point is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start from the top:

`foo(x, a)` has two parameters: `x` and `a`

`foo(-1, 10)` would mean that `x = -1` and `a = 10`.

From there go down each line.

`b = x - k` would start out as `b = -1 + (the value of k on that current iteration of the loop`

Then you would do the same for the `while` loop.

`x = -1 + 10 + 1`

So,

`x = 10`

Now take that value and plug it into the `while` loop condition:

`(10 > -2) and (10 < 2)`

Is this condition true? No. So you move on to the next iteration of the `for loop`

At the end you set `y` equal to the value you got for `b` + the value you got for `x`

Comment: I don't understand how ````x```` will be able to satisfy the ````while```` loop condition. Won´t ````x=10```` no matter what my ````k````-value is?

Comment: And maybe I have misunderstood the iterations of the ````for loop```` but can't ````k```` only be -1 and 0, if so how can I get ````b=10````?

Comment: The while loop will only have one iteration and set `x=10` When `k=0` then `b = 10 - 0`

Comment: Oh okay now I got it. Thank you very much! :)